# Law of Iterated Expectations applied thrice

Tags: probability, expected-value

If $U(Z(Y,X),Y(X),X)$, then

$$E(U)= E(E(E(E(U\mid Z)\mid Y)\mid X))$$

Will this hold?

I think so it should hold because if we assume $Z$ is constant, then were assuming $X$ and $Y$ are constant and similarly for $Y$ and $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but they should be iterated expectations, so the inner one should be conditional on $X,Y,Z$, the middle one on $X,Y$, the outer one on $X$ only (I think this is what you mean by $Y\left(X\right)$, etc.). Each time you are providing additional information on top of what was already known. Then, all of the usual properties of expectation carry over to conditional expectations.

Comment: I think when we're using the notation E(U|Z), we mean that z is given which is only possible when Y and X are given. So that notation alone defines Y and X as given?

Comment: Actually, Z being given does not mean that X and Y are given. Suppose Z = (X-Y)^2. Then it is possible to know Z but not X and Y. For this reason the convention is usually to explicitly write out all the random variables on which you are conditioning. But, to answer your question, the law of iterated expectations can indeed be nested as long as the sigma-algebras being conditioned on are nested as well.